# Ordenação de dicionario obtendo as values

Tags: python

Eu tenho a seguinte função que já fiz que é esta :

```
def funcao(elemento):
    x = []
    for i in grafico:
            timestring = i["CrimeTime"]
            x.append(timestring)
    x= sorted(x)

    y= Counter(x).values()
    return x,y
```

E  o que me dá é :

```
(['16:40:00', '16:45:00', '17:30:00', '18:30:00', '18:38:00', '20:00:00', '21:30:00', '21:30:00', '21:51:00'], [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Sendo o que me deveria dar é :

```
Código :
(['16:40:00', '16:45:00', '17:30:00', '18:30:00', '18:30:00', '20:00:00', '21:30:00', '21:30:00', '21:51:00'], [1, 1, 1, 2 , 1,2, 1])
```

O objetivo é obter as horas ordenadas que dá correto ,e o numero de vezes que cada hora se repete , sendo que os valores estao bem , não estão é corretamente posicionados( poderá ter a ver com o facto de ir buscar os valores a dicionario) mas não estou a ver como obtenho os valores corretamente ordenados

Answer (score 1):

Cara,

o que está acontecendo ao meu ver é, quando você chama `Counter(x)` está sendo criado um dicionário, utilizando os valores que estavam na sua lista como chaves e o número de vezes que aquele valor aparece na lista como o valor.

Quando você chama `.values()` no dicionário que foi criado, ele retorna os valores que estão presentes para cada chave, porém o dicionário não garante a ordenação.

Se você fizer o acesso chave por chave você verá que os valores estão corretos.

```
def funcao(elemento):
    x = []
    for i in grafico:
        timestring = i["CrimeTime"]
        x.append(timestring)
    x = sorted(x)        
    unique_x = sorted(set(x)) #remove os valores duplicados de x mantendo a ordenação
    count_x = Counter(x)
    y = [count_x[value] for value in unique_x]

    return x,y
```

Eu não sei quais são as suas reais necessidades, mas eu talvez retornaria apenas o dicionário, que já contem todas as informações desejadas.